# fopen for write never returns null

Tags: c, file, locking, stdio

I'm trying to build something simple to test out file locking. I try to open two files for write and both calls complete. After opening the file it reads: "hello world".

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  File *fp1 = fopen("./test.txt", "w");
  fwrite("hello", 1, 5, fp1);

  File *fp2;
  if (fp2 = fopen("./test.txt", "w")) {
    fwrite("      world", 1, 11, fp2);
  }
}
```

From the man page for fopen I was under the impression that if a file was open for write, the second call will return null. I found a similar case: [Opening a file using fopen with same flag in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723397/opening-a-file-using-fopen-with-same-flag-in-c); following the answer by Adhip Gupta I tried to check for <= 0 which also did not work.

I tried to use open() from fcntl.h as well. Two file descriptors were printed when I expected -1 for the second call.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() {
  int id1 = open("./text.txt", O_WRONLY);
  int id2 = open("./text.txt", O_WRONLY);
  printf("%d %d\n", id1, id2);
}
```

Why is this the case? I did not close file streams/descriptors when I did my testing; could that be a reason?

Comment: On what system the fopen man page says that? Can you post a quotation?

Comment: It is only because the man page does not explicitly mention that writes can occur concurrently. I assumed you cannot open two files for write since it can cause race conditions.

Comment: It's not clear how this issue relates to race conditions. If you do simultaneous writes through the *same* handle, you may have a race condition. But it's your responsibility to semaphore it away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly valid to open the same file more than once. You mention man pages and `fcntl.h`, so I presume that you're working on some unix variant. Unix doesn't lock files automatically when applications open them for writing. If program A and program B open the same file, their modifications will overwrite each other; this is useful, for example, when they are writing to different parts of the file. In your code, program A and program B are the same process.

Opening the same file twice isn't a special case. Each call to `open` gives you a file descriptor, and each file descriptor has its own position. Each call to `fopen` gives you a file descriptor and additionally an stdio write buffer. In your first example, where you write a small piece of data to each file, the `fwrite` call stores the data in the write buffer in memory; the data isn't actually written to the file until [`fflush()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush) is called. You don't explicitly call `fflush()`, nor `fclose()` which would call `fflush` (or achieve the same effect) under the hood. `fclose()` is implicitly called when your program exits, but there is no guarantee on the order in which the files are closed, so there are two possibilities, of which you're seeing the second:

- `fp1` is closed first, causing `"hello"` to be written at position 0. Then `fp2` is closed, causing `"      world"` to be written at position 0. This overwrites the 5 bytes written through `fp1`.
- `fp2` is closed first, causing `"      world"` to be written at position 0. Then `fp2` is closed, causing `"hello"` to be written at position 0. This overwrites the first 5 bytes written through `fp1`, leaving `"hello world"`.

Most unix systems only offer cooperative locks, through functions like [`lockf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/lockf) and [`fcntl`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl). If both programs call `lockf(fd, F_LOCK, size)` on the same file (not necessarily through the same file descriptor), then the second program to do so will block until the first one releases its lock. Any program can still modify the file by calling `write`. Some unix variants (for example [Linux](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/mandatory-locking.txt) do offer mandatory locks, which do affect programs whether they were aware of the lock or not.

Answer (score 3):

It's because when you use `"w"` as open mode for [`fopen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) it destroys the current content of the file and starts with a fresh new file. So when you call `fopen` a second time it will succeed because it doesn't care if the file exists or not, or if there's any content in it. If the path is correct and you have the correct permissions to open the file for writing, then the `fopen` call will succeed.

If you want to open a file for writing only, and fail if it already exists, you have to check for the file existence first yourself.

Comment: You can use `O_EXCL` with `O_CREAT` to `open` to fail if the file already exists. This prevents race conditions between checking and opening, which will exist if you make two separate function calls. However, `open` is not standard C, but is part of POSIX, so it may or may not work for your use case. As for "that status is stored in the system" — I don't think it's that complicated: you can just open the same file twice, if you really want. You do get a new descriptor.

Comment: This is half-wrong, half-irrelevant. The question isn't asking how to get `fopen` to refuse to open an existing file, but why it doesn't refuse to open a file that's already open. The `open` call doesn't return `-1`, not *because* the file is already opened, but because whether the file is already opened or not doesn't matter: if you call `open` twice, you get two file descriptors.

Comment: C11 also introduced the `x` flag for exclusive write access to a file, so `wx` will fail if the file exists (or cannot otherwise be created, e.g. no write permission for a directory), else it will create the file with exclusive access "to the extent that the underlying system supports exclusive access." I'm not certain if it is supported very much, so I'd stick with POSIX stuff for file locking right now. It is much more flexible anyway.