# How to make 2 file pointers write in one file sequentially in C++?

Tags: c++, file

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    int x = 2;

    FILE *fp [x];

    fp[0] = fopen ("temp.txt", "w");
    fp[1] = fopen ("temp.txt", "w");

    if (fp[1])
        qDebug () << "Fine";

    fputs ("What is your name?\n", fp[0]);
    fputs ("What is your name?\n", fp[0]);
    fputs ("What is your name?\n", fp[0]);

    fputs ("My name is XYZ.\n", fp[1]);

    fputs ("What is your name?\n", fp[0]);
    fputs ("What is your name?\n", fp[0]);


    fclose (*fp);

    return a.exec();
}
```

I am using Qt for the convenience sake.

Word "Fine" is being printed.
The output of this program is:

```
What is your name?
What is your name?
What is your name?
What is your name?
What is your name?
```

Why is `My name is XYZ.` missing from the output? What can be done to make these file pointers write sequentially in one file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borrowing from [Opening a file using fopen with same flag in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723397/opening-a-file-using-fopen-with-same-flag-in-c)

> You have 2 `FILE*` open to the same file, pointing at the beginning of
>   the file, so one of the writes overwrites the other.
>
> Note also that FILE* are normally buffered, so these small strings
>   actually gets written to the file when you fclose() or fflush() the
>   FILE*. Since you do neither, the system will do it when the
>   application exits , so which write gets overwritten depends on which
>   file the system closes first.
>
> If you open the 2 files in append mode , fopen("mytext","a");, you'll
>   see different result, but you'll need to fflush() the FILE* when you
>   want to make sure operating on the other FILE* doesn't cause
>   interleaved output. And writing to the same file from different
>   processes/threads will take more care, e.g. some form of file locking.

In your case you are closing `fp[0]` but not `fp[1]`. Both writes are independent and possibly `"My name is XYZ.\n"` is flushed into the file first (to the beginning) and then all the string `"What is your name?\n"` are flushed into the file from the beginning overwriting previous line.

> How to make 2 file pointers write in one file sequentially in C++?

Don't reopen the file using `fopen` and use the same file descriptor or use a log utility function which keeps a static pointer to opened file or open the file everytime you log and closes the file after logging.

```
static void log(char *line)
{
  static FILE *fp = fopen("temp.txt", "w");
  if(fp) fputs ("What is your name?\n", fp);
}
```

and later in main()

```
log("What is your name\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FILE *fp [x];

fp[0] = fopen ("temp.txt", "w");

fputs ("What is your name?\n", fp[0]);
fputs ("What is your name?\n", fp[0]);
fputs ("What is your name?\n", fp[0]);
fputs ("What is your name?\n", fp[0]);
fputs ("What is your name?\n", fp[0]);
fp[1] = fopen ("temp.txt", "w");
fputs ("My name is XYZ.\n", fp[1]);
```

Try like this.

Comment: Why should they? Add a bit of explanation.